# How to store html or any other code to database and retrieve display in asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

```
<script type ='text/Javascript'>
  var _gap=_gap||[];<br/>
 _gap.push(['_setAccount','UA-xxxxxxxxx-x']);
 _gap.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

**Submit Code to Database Form :**

this form contain one textbox and one button, wheneve i click this button whateve code that i entered into textbox that will 
store to database and retrieve that code from database and display in my another asp.net webpage like as shown below image

Next Form

> [in this form that code retrieve from database and display in syntax
>   highlighter format][1]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBU8L.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBU8L.jpg'/>

Answer (score 0):

Add the scripts or any html to database as **byte[]**

Steps:

1. Convert your scripts to byte[] and save this is database.
2. Retrieve  byte[] and convert to original then display in second page.

Comment: can you please post any sample code which belongs to my requirement

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer
**step 1 :** first add this ValidateRequest="false"  in page directive

**step 2 :** add this code in web.config file in asp.net

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web
```

**step 3 :** Button Click event Code

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string html = TextBox1.Text;
        Label1.Text = html;
    }
```